# Create a new command for mutt

Tags: mutt

I try to create a command (and not a macro) on mutt to print the mail in file, for this a put the following line on the `~/.muttrc`:

```
macro index,pager print-on-file '<enter-command>set print_command="muttprint -x --paper A4 --printer TO_FILE:/tmp/$USER.ps && zathura /tmp/$USER.ps"<enter>p' "Print on file and open it on the reader"
```

As you see, I try to make the command `<enter-command>set print_command="muttprint -x --paper A4 --printer TO_FILE:/tmp/$USER.ps && zathura /tmp/$USER.ps"<enter>p` by `:print-on-file` and not by pressing a single key.

I know `macro` isn’t the good command but I don’t found on the mutt’s configuration.

So, how to make a new command?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create new commands, only macros.

Comment: So, we are sure it isn’t possible?

Comment: You can still bind a macro to a sequence of keys, e.g. `macro index :print your_macro` but that's rather limited, you won't have feedback, it won't appear in the command history, and if you use `:` as the first key, Mutt will have to wait for a second key before you can see any effect with the usual `:`. You can also define user-defined variables, but I don't see how they can be useful here.